# Reversing the output of a range of numbers

Tags: python-3.x, range

```
 for n in range(10):
       print(str(n) * n)
```

I have the code down for the output

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

, but I have no clue on how to get the output

```
999999999
88888888
7777777
666666
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for n in range(9,0,-1):
       print(str(n) * n)
```

would produces

```
999999999
88888888
7777777
666666
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

The last argument of the range being negative indicate that we want a decrement.